# command similar to \underset

Tags: underline

Is there a command similar to `\underset` which doesn't minimize the elements under the text? I want to write a function in the usual way: set to set with the elements beneath them, but `\underline` shrinks them too much.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add `\textstyle` inside the `\underset` command. Alternatively, define a new command to do this for you:

```
\newcommand\Underset[2]{\underset{\textstyle #1}{#2}}
```

This produces:

[image]

Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Underset[2]{\underset{\textstyle #1}{#2}}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

Using \verb|\underset|:
\[ \underset{0\le x\le 1}{\max} f(x) \]
Using \verb|\Underset|:
\[ \Underset{0\le x\le 1}{\max} f(x) \]

\end{document}
```